# Removing £ from realurl url

Tags: php, typo3, realurl

Searching for a solution where TYPO3 7.6.4 and realurl 2.0.14 are the partners.

While building speaking urls for news entries with a '£' symbol in title, the URLs process this character and resulting in a 'pound' string.

News heading: £500 For Local Charity
speaking URL : news/pound500-for-local-charity

Is there a way to block this processing.

I am expecting the urls to be : news/500-for-local-charity

In my realurl_conf.php

```
'enableCHashCache'                => true,
'adminJumpToBackend'              => true,
'enableUrlDecodeCache'            => true,
'enableUrlEncodeCache'            => true,
'enableAllUnicodeLetters'         => true,
'doNotRawUrlEncodeParameterNames' => true,
'appendMissingSlash'              => 'false',
'emptyUrlReturnValue'             => '/'
```

Any similar issues or solution suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In realurl 1 there as an option encodeTitle_userProc under pagePath. With this it was possible to process the title with an userFunction and remove some entities like you want.

In the realurl 2 doc I can't find this option anymore but I hope it is still present. But under preVars, fixedPostVars and postVarSets this option seems to be still available: https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Configuration-reference#lookuptable

German article about this: http://blog.teamgeist-medien.de/2015/10/typo3-realurl-html-tags-aus-der-url-entfernen.html

EDIT: Another option is using the option realurl alias / overwrite realurl path in the page options (guess the news extension has this option too).